# Cant' Access API with Powershell but can access using Postman, Python, or cURL

Tags: powershell, request, invoke-webrequest, invoke-restmethod

I'm trying to get data back from an API online using Powershell with the command `Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing $request_string -Method Get -Headers $headers)` but am getting back `Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.`

I am supplying a $headers dictionary. Strangely, I can access the API using Postman, Python, and cURL. It's only when using Powershell commands that I get the 403 error. In fact, I used Postman's Code Snippet feature to generate my Powershell code, and it still doensn't work! Postman's Powershell Code Snippet was:

```
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer {removed for security}")

$response = Invoke-RestMethod '{removed for security}' -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers
$response | ConvertTo-Json
```

To recap, both `Invoke-WebRequest` and `Invoke-RestMethod` don't work.

Any help here is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: try this at the top of your script: [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;

Comment: I tried it, but still get the same error. In fact, I tried all the options ("SystemDefault,Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12,Tls13") except for Ssl3 (because the protocol is not supported on my work computer), and all returned a 403 error. 

Any other suggestions? I appreciate the first one!

Comment: nvm, figured it out. see the answer

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out on my own.

The API vendor enforced **https** requirement instead of just **http**. Apparently, Postman, Python, and cURL can figure that out on their own and change the request accordingly, but Powershell cannot.